# How do I name the comment.tpl.php file to use it in my own theme?

Tags: theming, comments

I have copied comment.tpl.php from mytheme/modules/comment into 
root/sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates. What should I name it to override the core template?

The form ID is *places-to-go-entry*. I tried comment--places-to-go-entry.tpl.php, but it didn't work.
The content type is *places_to_go_entry*. I tried both *comment-form--node-[content-type].tpl.php* and *comment-form--node-[places_to_go_entry].tpl.php*, but it didn't work.

I am looking to hide the subject area in comments and *Add new comments*, and modify *Permalink Submitted by Joe Smith on Sat, 03/30/2019 - 19:29*
to be *by Joe Smith 03/30/2019*.

Using template.php, I successfully hide the *New comment* subject label and dialog box, so I thought I'd go this route. I don't know what variables to work with to hide the subject area in the comments list, and I don't know know what variables modify for the permalink line.

Comment: try https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeformsettings

Comment: You don't change the name. Just copy the file to your theme folder, and clear your cache. The template file will be picked up from your theme folder.

Comment: Jaypan that worked for me but there is no checkmark next to your answer for me to be able to check!